# Calculate voltage when temperature is input

Tags: python

```
import math
#// resistance at 25 degrees C
THERMISTORNOMINAL = 10000
#// temp. for nominal resistance (almost always 
25 C)
TEMPERATURENOMINAL = 25
#// The beta coefficient of the thermistor (usually 3000-4000)
BCOEFFICIENT = 3950
#// the value of the 'other' resistor
SERIESRESISTOR = 10000

def calculate_temp(voltage):

    voltage = voltage / 1000
    # convert the value to resistance
    average = (SERIESRESISTOR / voltage) -  SERIESRESISTOR

    steinhart = average / THERMISTORNOMINAL            #// (R/Ro)
    steinhart = math.log(steinhart)                    #// ln (R/Ro)
    steinhart /= BCOEFFICIENT                          #// 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
    steinhart += 1.0 / (TEMPERATURENOMINAL + 273.15)   #// + (1/To)
    steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart                        #//     Invert
    steinhart -= 273.15                                #// convert to C

    # print("Temperature:", steinhart, "C");
    return round(steinhart, 2)
```

Above was the code of converting voltage to temperature.How can i convert temperature to voltage?

Comment: I am sorry about the code to be entered in an improper way

Comment: Can you please reformat your code?

Comment: By inverting the calculation? This doesn't appear to be a coding question as posed.

Comment: All the operations appear to be simple arithmetic. What's the issue?

Comment: Yep its a bit maths problem.I have been doing this research actually its steinhart equation.So while finding voltage you have to entor Vin and in output u het vcc

Comment: Is there some step that you don't know how to reverse? I could see if, say, you didn't know how to do the opposite of `math.log`, but I don't want to just wildly guess where your math knowledge might fall down.

Comment: Also, it might help to give the intermediate values useful names instead of calling them all `steinhart`, and track the units for each step (maybe even with a real units-and-quantities library, but probably just comments are fine); then it'll be easier to verify that you're doing each step right (and, if you get stuck somewhere, easier for us to understand what the step you're stuck on is supposed to accomplish).